# setting height of a div in jquery ui layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-layout

Ive been experimenting with the adjustable grids plugin (jquery ui layout).. I was able to set the width of each divs using the plugins.. bt when it comes to height ive only been allowed to adjust the heights of outer div. I was wondering if it is possible to to adjust the height of inner north div ive added in the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/J4bJ3/1/

ive tried `$("#facetContainer").css({"height":"50%"});`
on load time. bt it will not wrk

Answer (score 2):

A lot of those ui elements have settings that need to be overridden in css using !important have you tried eliminating css as the culprit already?

**edit**

If I change:

```
.ui-layout-pane-south {           
    border:          1px solid #BBB;
    overflow:        hidden;
}
```

to:

```
.ui-layout-pane-south {           
    height:          230px !important;
    border:          1px solid #BBB;
    overflow:        hidden;
}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

And when using an id on an element, implement the rule as follows:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I overlooked it the first time. Sorry about that. I updated my answer and it seems that this does the trick.

Comment: Sam, did this answer your question? If so, could you please mark the answer. If not, what went wrong?

Comment: actually there are two divs with the same name ui-layout-north, as u can see in the jsfiddle.. thats y i tried using an id... bt that dint wrk.. ive tried ur answer.. it actually breaks the div elements

Comment: the inner north cant be resized as the original version and im nt resizing all ui north panes...thats y i tried using ids

Comment: did you try resizing the line above inner center div??

Comment: What you're writing does not make any sense. Resizing a line? The "lines" above the divs are spacings between them. Using the method I've described you may change every div in your example. I added the pictures for clarification, proving that the div with the id may be resized independently. I cannot find another way to read your question so this is my answer. Should this not be what you meant, please update your question and try to use full words, please.

Comment: by line, i meant the resizing grid above inner center div in jsfiddle.. try resizing tht.. you will find the fault..

Comment: Quickest solution to that is inserting a div in between and set the height of that element to the spacing you'd like.